# How to make a Reaction role command with discord.py

Tags: discord.py

So I'm trying to make a Reaction role via discord.py but i don't know how to do it. Also there is no tutorial on YT, I want the bot to send a message and react to that message so the user when react to that get the role.

Comment: what have you tried so far? Any code?

Answer (score 0):

Okay,
This uses cogs and a bot instead of a client.

```
message = await ctx.send(" Click the ✅ reaction to verify yourself")
```

This piece sends the message (You can change it to whatever you want).

```
    if not get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Verified"):
                perms = discord.Permissions()
                perms.general()
                perms.text()
                perms.voice()
                await ctx.guild.create_role(name="Verified", permissions=perms, colour=discord.Colour(0x00bd09))
```

This piece will just check whever the role exists or not. If it doesnt it will create one.

```
await message.add_reaction("✅")
```

This adds this reaction to the message(So the user doesnt have to scroll around for it). If you dont want the bot have the role, you can add a check (If the user is a bot or not) in the `on_raw_reaction_add()` function.

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
        guild = self.bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
        role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Verified")
        await payload.member.add_roles(role, reason="Verified Self", atomic=True)
```

This is the function to check when someone adds a reaction to the message. We want to use `on_raw_reaction_add()` instead of `on_reaction_add()` because the second one check the cache for adding a reaction, and if the thing isnt in chache it wont work. Thus the 1st one is less probable to create problems.
Here's the whole piece.

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, CheckFailure

class Verification(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

@commands.command(name='generate_verification', help='Generates verification message')
    async def generate_verification(self, ctx):


        message = await ctx.send(" Click the ✅ reaction to verify yourself")

        verification_message_id = message.id


        # Check if Verification role already exists

        if not get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Verified"):
            perms = discord.Permissions()
            perms.general()
            perms.text()
            perms.voice()

            await ctx.guild.create_role(name="Verified", permissions=perms, colour=discord.Colour(0x00bd09))

        await message.add_reaction("✅")

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
        guild = self.bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
        role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Verified")
        await payload.member.add_roles(role, reason="Verified Self", atomic=True)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Verification(bot))
```

If you're creating a verification command, then you probably would like to store the amount of verification messages sent in a file. This would stop people from generating the message a lot of times. To this you also probably want a command to clear the data from the file, so if the adming wants to create the message again he just needs to clear the file.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I wanted to create a custom message through command, I am new to discord.py so struggling so much.